# How to animate a UISearchBar sliding in and out of the view without a UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have a view that has a button which toggles a `UISearchBar` using

```
searchBar.hidden = !searchBar.hidden;
```

The searchbar goes out and queries a web service to get results and then displays them to the user without ever using a `UITableView` or a local datasource or anything. As such I don't really want to use a UISearchDisplayController to do the animation.

Is there anyway to animate this sliding without manually coding up the animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and use the UISearchDisplayController.  It's not a terribly heavyweight object.  Any code you write to replace its functionality is certainly going to have a bigger footprint than an instance of a class you've already got in the UIKit.